# Is it possible to use one parameter's type for another parameter?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function for dispatching an update to a store:

```
updateData<T>(entity: T, prop: keyof T, value: any): void {
  const action: Action = new SaveAction(entity, {[prop]: value});
  store.dispatch(action);
}
```

In the example, let's assume `T` is a class representing a question, which looks something like this:

```
class Question {
  readonly content: string;
  readonly answer: string;
  readonly score: number;

  constructor(obj: Stringified<Question>) {
    this.content = obj.content;
    this.answer = obj.answer;
    this.score = obj.score;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to make this function more type-safe by ensuring that the `value` parameter only accepts values with the type corresponding to the property?

Using the above example, I'd like the TSLint or the Typescript compiler to save me from doing something like

```
updateData<Question>(someQuestion, 'score', 'some string');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
updateData<T, K extends keyof T>(entity: T, prop: K, value: T[K]): void {
  const action: Action = new SaveAction(entity, {[prop]: value});
  store.dispatch(action);
}
```

where the `value` parameter uses a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to constrain it to the relevant property type for that key.  And you just call it without explicitly specifying the type parameter (leave off the `<Question>`):

```
updateData(someQuestion, 'score', 123); // okay
updateData(someQuestion, 'score', 'some string'); // error: 
// Argument of type '"some string"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

Hope that helps; good luck!